# "Could not generate DH key pair on the destination URL" error

Tags: firewall, https, tls

What could cause a `Could not generate DH key pair on the destination URL` error?

A EDI partner company tries to connect to our HTTPS server and encounters the above message.

Or system uses a commercial firewall and reverse proxy (Apache based) with a high security ranking ('A' at qualsys ssltest). I suspect that our security level is higher than the capabilities of our EDI partner company, however they claim to have working connections with other HTTPS partners, and they say that they support '2048 bits'.

Unfortunately we can not lower the security level in our system for test purposes. Are there standard diagnostics tools which we can recommend our EDI partner so that they can analyze the connection failure?

---

Update: I used the Qualsys diagnostics tool for SSL and found that for Java (Sun JRE) 6 clients no connection is possible because

`Java 6u45 - Client does not support DH parameters > 1024 bits`.

For other A-rated servers however, Java 6 clients can connect, and it seems that they just do not use DH:

`Java 6u45 - TLS 1.0 - TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)`

So if I put these pieces together, I assume that our server insists on DH key exchange (which is not supported for Java 6 clients), while other servers are able to negotiate a different cipher so that Java 6 clients can connect. However I am not an expert in this area, so please let me know if I am chasing a red herring :)

Comment: This is usually due to code that only supports 1024bit DH, but then again they claim to support 2048bit >.< These might guide you in the right direction...
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/Could+not+generate+DH+keypair+on+SSL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851461/java-why-does-ssl-handshake-give-could-not-generate-dh-keypair-exception

Comment: What software is generating the error?  What DH parameters are being negotiated?  Whether the claim of supporting "2014 bits" is relevant depends very much on *which* part of the system supports that many bits.  Finally, the standard tools are `less` (to view the logs), `wireshark` (to see what's going over the wire), and `telephone` (to call whoever wrote the software at the far end and get them to help with their opaque and out-of-date software).

Comment: "2014 bits" is unlikely. You were probably speaking to a dyslexic who meant "1024 bits".

Comment: @MichaelHampton oops this was a simple typo

Comment: @BinaryCode many thanks this looks like a potential solution (rearranging the cipher suite)

Comment: Java 6 has also been past end-of-life for several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all DHE ciphers from our server finally solved the connection problem.